# list-group in form element - bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I read Bootstrap 3 documentation on form and supported controls in forms.
For selection, I can use `<select>` and `<select multiple>`.

But I want a nicer select-box, exactly like `list-group` class bootstrap has.
`list-group` can have rendered items, while as the `<select>` can only have textual `<option>`s.

The main idea is so that I can do `$("form").serializeArray()` and get all of it as JSON, which apparently will not work if I stick a `list-group` as a form control.

Any ideas on how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create what you need with jquery ?

**Fiddle :** http://bootply.com/113041

**HTML :**

```
<select id="myselect" multiple="">
  <option val="1">1</option>
  <option val="2">2</option>
  <option val="3">3</option>
  <option val="4">4</option>
  <option val="5">5</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselect').hide().after("<ul class='list-group'></ul>");
    $('#myselect option').each(function(){
          $('.list-group').append("<li class='list-group-item' opt='"+$(this).attr('val')+"'>"+$(this).html()+"</li>"); 
    });
    $('.list-group li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        var allVal = new Array();
        $('.list-group li.active').each(function(){
             allVal.push(  $(this).attr('opt' ) );
        });
        $('#myselect').val(allVal);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
li.active{
  background:cyan;
}
```

**Result :** A bootstrap list-group, who is linked to your select

Comment: I like to use javascript as less as possible, especially when getting data off of a form. I use 1 function, JSON-ize the form, and that's it. it works only with supported form controls though... so I was just looking for a "nicer" multi select. thanks.